# n:m relations of lines including directions

Tags: qgis, postgresql, database, relates

For trail planning and route signalization projects, I am looking for a solutions which allows me to connect "physical" trail segments (available as .gdb from authorities) with overlaying routes, whereas the routes may follow the segments in both directions.

The routes should be stored in a Postgres DB.

I assume this is a n:m relation, but how should the directions be manageed?
Routes normally consist of >1 segment and there are likely to be more than one route on one segment.

I use QGIS 2.14 on Mac OSX, postgres 11.

Comment: This question is too broad and too vague to really allow a specific answer. Here are a couple of references you might find helpful: https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#creating-one-to-many-relations, https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html